# Tell if a class is conforming to specific protocol method at runtime?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, protocols

I'm trying to tell if there is a way to determine if a class is conforming to a specific (optional) protocol method at runtime. Is there a way to check for this? Don't want to send a call to a nonexistent delegate method implementation in the delegate class.

Comment: -[NSObject respondsToSelector:]?

Comment: a class "conforms to" a protocol and "responds to" a method (a selector). It does not "conform to a method".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 BOOL isProtocolConformed=[YourClass conformsToProtocol:@protocol(YourProtocol)];
 BOOL isSelectorResponse=[yourObject respondsToSelector:@selector(yourMethod)];
 if(isProtocolConformed && isSelectorResponse){
    //do your stuff
 }
```

Comment: That won't tell you if the class actually implements the *optional* method.

Comment: This will return just the specified method and not just whether the class conforms to the protocol generally?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Didn't see it :)

Comment: @Storms What you're looking for is a combination of both. Check if the class conforms to the protocol and then check if it actually responds to the optional method. But I'd argue that the protocol check is redundant, thus you can safe yourself that check.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(protocolMethod)])
{
    [self.delegate protocolMethod];
}
```

From [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:):

> ### respondsToSelector:
>
> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver implements or inherits a method that can respond to a specified message.